# SQL Server Copy Wizard - copy failing

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to copy a SQL Server database from my laptop development machine to a test machine.

Both are running Windows 8.1 Premium and SQL Server 2014 Development. Using SSMS I can access each server and create databases and amend security details, so the actual network connection and my own credentials are fine.

Firewalls are turned of for private networks.

My laptop SQL SERVER is named LIAM-LAPTOP\LIAMDEV and the test machine is BEAST\BEAST (it made me smile at the time...).

When I run the database copy wizard, it comes up with the following error:

```
Event Name: OnError
    Message: An error occurred while transferring data. See the inner exception for details.
    StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer.TransferData()
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.TransferObjectsTask.TransferObjectsTask.TransferExtraObjectsViaSmoTransfer()
    InnerException-->Windows NT user or group 'NT SERVICE\SQLAgent$LIAMDEV' not found. Check the name again.
```

I've looked around and I have a feeling that it's access rights from BEAST to LIAM-LAPTOP as they are in different domains, but I can't see how I change it.

Comment: Why use the wizard?  Can't you just take a backup of the DB and restore it to your test environment?

Comment: That's what I've done for now, but I'm fairly new to SQL Server and thought I'd try and understand what was wrong with it as next time I may not have a decent work around...

Comment: As a DBA, I try to avoid using SSMS GUI things like DB Copy Wizard, Import/Export Wizard, etc.  Scripted approaches are usually better and allow finer control over what you are doing.  While that doesn't answer your question (hence why this is a comment, not an answer), it does hopefully point you down the path or what most of us DBAs prefer.